# How to replace basic HTML dropdown created by ajax call with the HtmlDropdown helper

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So, I have two drodpowns, both dropdowns are working as expected. So, entry in second dropdowns determined by the entry selected in first drodpown. Also, I have added a script call `CountrySelectionChanged` on the page reload too so that second dropdown gets populated as per the intitial value of first dropdown.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            CountrySelectionChanged();
        });
 </script>      
<div id="Admin">
        Select an account:
        @Html.DropDownList("countrySelection", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AvailableAccounts, new { onchange = "CountrySelectionChanged()"})
        <p id="Temp">
            Select a city:
            <select id="City" name="City"></select>
        </p>
  </div>

    AJAX CALL:
    function CountrySelectionChanged() {
    // logic taken out for brevity
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Settings/GetCity',
        data: { accountId: accountId },
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            var locationDropdown = '';
            for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                locationDropdown += '<option value="' + data[x].Value + '">' + data[x].Text + '</option>';
            }
             $('#City').html(locationDropdown);
        },
        error: function () {
            DisplayError('Failed to load the data.');
        }
    });
```

}

**Question:** Is there a way that I can use HTML Helper to display second dropdown too? Can I somehow inject the ajax return to a HTML Helper (Even if it's not strongly bound).

Comment: This is called a "cascading dropdown" if you want to lookup examples in MVC, like [this one](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-using-razor/) I found

Comment: Yes, the selection in second dropdown is dependent on the first dropdown.

Comment: So if I select first dropdown, I make an ajax call and build my dropdown options for the second dropdown in the ajax call.

Comment: @zgood: Worked like a charm. Thank you so so much. :)

Comment: That link is not a good example and means you lose data if you need to return the view, and cannot be used for editing existing data. Suggest you study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym).

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I will look into your solution. But before that can you kindly elaborate on what do you mean when you say "`you lose data if you need to return the view`. So as of now, suppose I select a country it shows me the list of states for that country in the 2nd dropdown. So, till now it did what was expected of it. So can you kindly tell me what will be the requirement that this code will fail to deliver. Once I know the flaw I will be able to understand your solution (link provided by you) in a much better way.

Comment: There are multiple issues with that code linked by @zgood (too long to add here) so I'll add comments in our other [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151554/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-stephen-muecke)